# How to send PHP $_GET variable with $_POST method when using it in SQL INSERT query?

Tags: php, mysql, get

I have a (subject) and (page) TABLES in a database.

**page** TABLE belongs to **subject** TABLE, each subject has an **ID**

When user click on a subject **mysite/blog?subject=(ID gets set__)** 1,2,3,4,5

So i want pages to be INSERTED according to in which subject they are in URL.

Well, i'm sending data using POST form to a (form_process.php) page.

```
<?php       
     if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
         $Message = $_POST["Content"];

         $query  = "INSERT INTO page ";
         $query .= "(Message, SubjectID) ";
         $query .= "VALUES ('{$Message}', $_GET['subject'])";
         $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

         if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection) > 0){
           echo "Page added to its beloging subject";
         }
     }
?>
```

I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined index: subject in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\kerimgrozny\public\blog.php on line 64

The problem is: when using $_GET variable in INSERT query as FOREIGN KEY,
It gets undefined.

The link on GitHub: https://github.com/kerimgrozny/kerimgrozny.git

Comment: Which line is line 64?

Comment: $subject = $_GET[subject];                                                                       $query .= " VALUES ('{$Message}', {$subject} )";

Comment: Also, you haven't shown where you're using $_GET[subject] in the PHP code where you're doing the query...

Comment: Have you tried echoing out $subject? I know you've tried $_GET['subject'], but it's worth checking if that's gone into $subject (I'm guessing it hasn't)

Comment: Are the two code blocks from the same PHP file (blog.php)? Also, you should be worried about [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 0):

replace

> $query .= "VALUES ('{$Content}', {$subject} )";

by

> $query .= "VALUES ('{$Content}', '{$subject}' )";

Hope it help you.